# API returning an object instead of string

Tags: c#, api, refit

I have an API that I set calls with refit, however when calling it I'm receiving an object instead of a string, I don't get what the issue is here.

```
var userToken = await apiClient.LoginuserBySsnAsync(ssn);
```

the definition of the API call:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Login user by SSN.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ssn">user SSN in 12 digit format.</param>
        /// <returns>user token.</returns>
        [Get("/api/login/loginssn")]
        Task<string> LoginUserBySsnAsync(string ssn);
```

and in this case the return I'm getting in "userToken" is:

```
"{\"userToken\":\"rgkjnrekljgtlwgktkwljhnglterkjhnyJuYmYiOjE2NDM2NjAxNDMsImV4cCI6MTY0NjA3OTM0MywiUGF0aWVudHNzbiwerlfkrlkgfnrejgnlrekjglmeMc\"}"
```

when I execute in the API directly (swagger) the response I get is:

```
{
  "userToken": "rgkjnrekljgtlwgktkwljhnglterkjhnyJuYmYiOjE2NDM2NjAxNDMsImV4cCI6MTY0NjA3OTM0MywiUGF0aWVudHNzbiwerlfkrlkgfnrejgnlrekjglmeMc"
}
```

where what I would expect is:

```
"rgkjnrekljgtlwgktkwljhnglterkjhnyJuYmYiOjE2NDM2NjAxNDMsImV4cCI6MTY0NjA3OTM0MywiUGF0aWVudHNzbiwerlfkrlkgfnrejgnlrekjglmeMc"
```

I'm not sure what the issue is as I don't have a lot of experience here, but I appreciate any help to improve

Comment: Those two responses are exactly the same.

Comment: I have added the expected and actual result.

Comment: What reason do you have to expect that output?

Comment: You get a json object as string, simply parse it for example with json.net: `Token token = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(userToken);`. Then you can access what you need with `token.userToken`

Comment: Can you show the implementation of that `LoginUserBySsnAsync` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API is returning a JSON-serialized object. Probably something like this:

```
public class UserTokenClass {
    public string UserToken { get; set; }
}

[Get("/api/login/loginssn")]
public async Task<string> LoginUserBySsnAsync(string ssn) {
    
    // Magic

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserTokenClass { UserToken = userTokenFromSomewhere });
}
```

If you want it to return just a plain string, then do that:

```
return userTokenFromSomewhere;
```

If you don't have any control over the API code, then deserialize the response in your code:

```
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserTokenClass>(responseBody);
```